# Image upload fails w/ nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to upload an image using Node w/ express and I get the following error. I have seen a few questions on this that point to asynch DB calls as the cause of the problem. I would like to use bodyParser as in theory, bodyParser should just pass me to connect and then formidable so I would prefer solutions that do not disable bodyParser.

In my case, I am making no DB calls - all my code is copied below. Any light that anyone could shed on this would be greatly appreciated.

> 500 Error: parser error, 40 of 44 bytes parsed at IncomingForm.write
>   (/Users/me/Projects/Project/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:145:17)
>   at IncomingMessage.
>   (/Users/me/Projects/Project/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:95:12)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17) at HTTPParser.onBody
>   (http.js:121:23) at Socket.ondata (http.js:1026:22) at
>   Socket._onReadable (net.js:683:27) at IOWatcher.onReadable [as
>   callback] (net.js:177:10)

Here is my app.js file (coffee script):

```
express = require('express')
routes = require('./routes')
app = module.exports = express.createServer()

app.configure(() ->
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')
  app.use(express.bodyParser({
    uploadDir: '/tmp/upload'
  }))
  app.use(express.methodOverride())
  app.use(express.cookieParser())
  app.use(app.router)
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
)

app.configure('development', () ->
  app.use(express.logger())
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }))
)

app.configure('test', () ->
  app.use(express.logger())
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }))
)

app.configure('production', () ->
  app.use(express.logger())
  app.use(express.errorHandler())
)

app.get('/images/new', (req, res) ->
    console.log("getting image form")
    res.render('forms/image_upload', {title: 'Images'})
)

app.post('/images', (req, res) ->
    console.log("post run")
    res.send('uploaded')
)

app.listen(3000, () ->
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env)
)
```

Here is my form partial (jade):

```
form#new-images(action="/images", enctype="multipart/form-data", method="post" )
    input#image-url(placeholder="Enter image url", type="text")
    input#image-files(type="file", multiple="multiple")
    input#submit(type="submit", value="Upload")
```

Here is are my packages (npm ls)

```
├─┬ connect-form@0.2.1 
│ └── formidable@1.0.11 
├─┬ connect-mongodb@1.1.4 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.5 
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11 
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.5 
│ │ └── qs@0.5.0 
│ └─┬ mongodb@1.0.2 
│   └── bson@0.0.6 
├─┬ express@2.5.9 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.7 
│ │ └── formidable@1.0.11 
│ ├── mime@1.2.4 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ └── qs@0.4.2 
├── expresso@0.9.2 
├── formidable@1.0.11 
├─┬ jade@0.26.1 
│ ├── commander@0.5.2 
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
├── knox@0.0.9 
├── less@1.3.0 
├─┬ mongoose@2.6.5 
│ ├── hooks@0.2.1 
│ └─┬ mongodb@1.0.2 
│   └── bson@0.0.6 
├─┬ multipart@0.1.5 
│ └── mime@1.2.6 
├─┬ session-mongoose@0.0.2 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.7 
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11 
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.5 
│ │ └── qs@0.5.0 
│ └── mongeese@0.0.1 
├─┬ socket.io@0.9.6 
│ ├── policyfile@0.0.4 
│ ├── redis@0.6.7 
│ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.6 
│   ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1 
│   │ └── zeparser@0.0.5 
│   ├── uglify-js@1.2.5 
│   ├─┬ ws@0.4.19 
│   │ ├── commander@0.5.2 
│   │ ├── options@0.0.3 
│   │ └── tinycolor@0.0.1 
│   └── xmlhttprequest@1.2.2 
└── sys@0.0.1
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've run into this exact problem before. Try and add a "name" value to each of your input tags. That did the trick for me.